# Is it possible to display items from a data model in a Flow layout?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Looking the documentation, it seems that Qt Quick's [Flow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html) type can be used for displaying items. But [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-viewtransition.html) seems to imply that the only options for displaying data from data models are ListView and GridView. Is that correct? Would there be a simple way to construct a flow-like item for displaying data from, e.g., a ListModel?

(I'm trying to make a transition from Qt Widgets to Qt Quick, if that explains any gaps in my thinking about this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is very much possible :-)

Use a [Repeater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html):

```
Flow {

    Repeater {
        model: your_model

        delegate: Button { } //or whatever you like
    }
}
```

Comment: Some time on I'm getting around to implementing this... with a large number of items, use of the Repeater becomes very slow. Is there another way to make it work?

Comment: Hmm, not really sure. I think it might have to do with the fact that a Repeater simply throws all the items it knows in the field. You might be better of with a view that does it's own creation handling and some caching, such as the mentioned GridView or ListView

Comment: Can i use the above code as delegate for listview ?

Comment: Yes, you use the delegate line in the same way and the model property from the ListView itself (so remove Repeater)